# Looping through Linq query to a list Throws IEnumerable Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, list, loops

I have this problem where I perform a Linq query then convert it to a List object. Let me add that this error only occurs sometimes and it happens in production. When i then resume to iterate through the list, I get an IEnumerable error. I have a logger set up and this is the exception type and stack trace. Any thoughts on how i can refactor this snippet of code to make it more stable would be much appreciated.
Here is the code which throws the error

```
var isMember = db.DN2_Member.Where(m =>
            m.Partner_Contract_Nbr.ToLower() == member.DentalMemberId.ToLower()
            && m.Mbr_First_Nm.ToLower() == member.DentalMemberFirstName.ToLower()
            //&& m.Mbr_Mid_Nm.ToLower().Trim() == memberMiddleName.ToLower()
            && m.Mbr_Last_Nm.ToLower() == member.DentalMemberLastName.ToLower()
            && m.DW_Rec_End_Dt == null 
            && m.Mbr_Suc_Title.ToLower() == membersuffix.ToLower().Replace(".", ""));

//Forces the query to evaluate to a definitive collection; necessary for querying it further
var memberList = isMember.ToList();

foreach (var record in memberList)
{
     record.Mbr_Mid_Nm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(record.Mbr_Mid_Nm.Trim()) ? "" : record.Mbr_Mid_Nm.Trim().Substring(0, 1); 
}
```

The Error is thrown on the `foreach (var record in memberList)`Line--this is line 88

Here is the logger information

> Exception Type: An error occurred while executing the command
>   definition. See the inner exception for details.
>
> Stack Trace:  at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext
>   context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1
>   func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean
>   startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass3.b__1()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1
>   operation) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.b__0()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext() at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) at
>   DentalTHSEnrollmentService.WebHost.THSService.GetMember(DentalMember member) in e:\GoAgent\pipelines\DentalTHSEnrollmentService_Master\product\app\DentalTHSEnrollmentService.WebHost\THSService.svc.cs:line 88

Now I can not recreate this error unless it is in production. Not sure why the code fails out when trying to loop through the list collection.

Comment: Are you sure that your schema and db columns are sync ?

Comment: Have you looked at the inner exception?

Comment: I guess I need to add the Inner Exception to the logger, thought the exception type and stack trace would be sufficient. and the service does pass most of the time, just this error keeps coming up, therefore, schema is not the issue, if some transactions are passing

Comment: I think your production db schema is different from development db. That is *probably* why you are getting the exception only at production.

Comment: If my schema is different how are some transactions passing? for example the same person uses this service and on the third time it will finally pass or so forth

Comment: Might depend on the actual parameter values used in the query. Are you executing three times with the same parameters and it passes after the third try?

Comment: Yes, the same form values are submitted to the service. Seems Entity framework is very unstable imo

Comment: @devzim It may fail if the actual DB type allows nulls but the .NET type does not. Have you looked at the `InnerException`?

Comment: The logger is setup to send the exception type and stacktrace, i just added exeption.ToString() to my logger to get the full details. Thought someone may be able to give insight on the stack trace i presented.

Comment: We have given insight, the inner exception may contain important info.

Comment: From the Stack Trace it looks that the exception is thrown from `isMember.ToList()` call, not when you iterate the result.